# Data Import Wizard Matching

Tags: data-import-wizard

Can you match by multiple criteria in Data Import Wizard?  I only see 1 'Match By' option available.  I'd like to match by 2 or more fields for updating...(Name, City..etc.).

Answer (score 4):

There is **no** option to add additional `Match By` attributes in the Data Import Wizard. The attribute is used to *uniquely* identify records, and this is from the help text for the attribute:

> Unique values in your data (for example, ID values or email values) help Salesforce determine whether to add new records or update existing records.

Your option here could be to create a new field which is marked as both External Id & Unique, and consists the data in the combination you want (e.g., Name & City), and then be able to utilize that field for matching.